# How to get historical data on transactions performed by smart contracts on Solana?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

How shall I go about getting new and historical data from Solana smart contracts? For example, I want to get data on recent swaps on Raydium.

When I developed on Ethereum, I used to parse historical events that are stored on the blockchain. Is there a similar method on Solana?

I would prefer to do it with Python, but other languages will be ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSignaturesForAddress` to get all of the signatures for a specific program, such as the Raydium Program.

You can then use `getTransaction` to get the details on each transaction. Alternatively you get your own rpc and use the internal bigtable.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction